# Проблема с перезаписью файла при загрузке со страницы браузера (Vue 3, ASP .Net 6)

Tags: vue.js, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, vue3, filestream

Столкнулась со следующей проблемой. У меня есть написанное WebAPI приложение на .Net 6, к которому с запросами обращается фронт, написанный на Vue 3. В разных местах приложения необходимо загружать файлы. Если файл загружаю в первый раз, проблем никаких, но стоит попробовать загрузить файл с таким же именем - начинаются проблемы.

Сначала я на странице в браузере выбираю файл, который нужно загрузить. Затем через axios отправляю POST запрос на сервер, где этот файл должен сохраняться.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.file);
axios({
   method: 'post',
   url: '/admin/offer/save',
   headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
   data: formData
}).then((request) => { show_message(request); });
```

Далее на сервере этот файл сохраняю.

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(uploadsFolder);
if (!dirInfo.Exists)
    dirInfo.Create();

var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
string fileName = file.FileName;
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, fileName);

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath + path, FileMode.Create))
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
```

Я пробовала `FileMode.Create`, так как нужно, чтобы новый загруженный файл перезаписывал старый. Пробовала удалять из папки старый и записывать новый файл. Ни одно, ни другое не помогло решить проблему. Код C# отрабатывает нормально, файл перезаписывается, данные в БД уходят нормально, но на странице выскакивает ошибка `SocketException: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.`
Думала попробовать при сохранении файла сразу давать ему уникальное имя, но когда пробую менять имя файла, снова - код C# работает нормально, в БД сохраняет корректно, но в этом случае в консоль браузера выходит ошибка

```
GET http://localhost:50598/js/12.js [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 2492ms]
Загрузка <script> по адресу «http://localhost:50598/js/12.js» не удалась. add_factory_order:1:1
[Vue Router warn]: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 12 failed.
(error: http://localhost:50598/js/12.js) vue-router.esm-bundler.js:62
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Couldn't resolve component "default" at "/show_factory_order/:id"
    extractComponentsGuards vue-router.esm-bundler.js:1959
    promise callback*extractComponentsGuards/< vue-router.esm-bundler.js:1957
    runGuardQueue vue-router.esm-bundler.js:3213
    promise callback*runGuardQueue/< vue-router.esm-bundler.js:3213
    runGuardQueue vue-router.esm-bundler.js:3213
    navigate vue-router.esm-bundler.js:2980
    promise callback*navigate vue-router.esm-bundler.js:2972
    pushWithRedirect vue-router.esm-bundler.js:2867
    push vue-router.esm-bundler.js:2816
    formSubmit add_factory_order.vue:201
    promise callback*formSubmit add_factory_order.vue:196
    4 add_factory_order.vue:18
    callWithErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:157
    callWithAsyncErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:166
    invoker runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:345
vue-router.esm-bundler.js:1959
```

И так во всех местах, где я пытаюсь загрузить файл. Подозреваю, что какая-то проблема возникает именно во Vue. Но что именно и как это решить совершенно не понимаю.

Comment: Я всегда во Vue для имен файлов +random_int(1, 10000). Соответственно при замене старый - как вы и делаете удаляем - новый - С НОВЫМ именем пишем (в частности это снимает кэш-проблемы при использовании компонентов для картинок в админке - при вызове поста для изменения)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема действительно заключалась в том, что имя файла нужно было менять до отправки на сервер. Написала метод, который добавляет в конец имени файла рандомную строку

```
export function insertSubstringBeforeExtension(filename) {
    const dotIndex = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (dotIndex === -1) {
        // Расширение файла отсутствует, просто добавляем подстроку в конец
        return filename + randomString;
    }
    const extension = filename.slice(dotIndex); // Получаем расширение файла
    const filenameWithoutExtension = filename.slice(0, dotIndex); // Получаем имя файла без расширения
    const randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 8); // Генерируем случайную строку
    return filenameWithoutExtension + randomString + extension;
}
```

И потом вызвала его перед отправкой (новое имя файла я положила в третий параметр FormData)

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.file, insertSubstringBeforeExtension(this.file.name));
```